# Keep getting a missing right parenthesis (ORA-00907) error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Just recently started learning SQL and got assigned some homework.
I have to make a few tables but I keep getting an ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis error but I see no syntax issues.

This is my code for one of the tables I have to make:

```
CREATE TABLE DRIVER 
(
    DRIVER# INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME VARCHAR(255), 
    SALARY INT,
    CERT_DATE DATE,
    DEPOT# INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DEPOT(DEPOT#)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your foreign key constraint at the end of the table definition (for column `DEPOT#`) is an **inline** constraint: it is defined "in line" with the column definition.

The syntax for inline foreign key constraints does not include the `FOREIGN KEY` keywords. The fix is trivial: delete those two words, then the statement should work.

As an aside, please note that for silly reasons the preferred data type for strings in Oracle database is `VARCHAR2` rather than `VARCHAR`. You may either research "why" on your own, ask your instructor, use `VARCHAR2` without asking why, or use `VARCHAR` knowing that Oracle recommends explicitly against its use.

Comment: Thank you so much, funny how simple the error was